# Accessing out-of-scope members

Tags: android

I have a fragment which contains a RecyclerView and sets it up with an Adapter separated in an own class.

In the fragment class I have a private boolean member which indicates whether the application is in "two pane" mode or not. This member gets updated in the onActivityCreated method.

I gotta use this variable in the adapter. 
Previously the classes were nested, so I could directly access it. Now it is in another scope.

I have two ideas:
1. Simply make the member public and static (seems a little bit unprofessional because I don´t want it to be changed from outside)
2. Use an own NotifyDataChanged class to which both the fragment and adapter can subscribe.

What is the best practice doing this in android?

Comment: can't you determine inside the `Adapter` if it's two pane mode? or pass the variable in constructor

Comment: you can copy value of that variable into another and make it public static

Comment: Why not just have a getter method in the Fragment class?

Comment: @giannisf It´s changed when the device is rotated, is there a proper callback in the adapter lifecycle?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell then I have to pass a reference to the adapter. Don´t know about memory leaks..

Answer (score 0):

Can't you place the boolean flag in the Activity and pass context in the Adapter's constructor, then check the flag's state through context in where you need to use it?

Comment: It´s never a good idea to hold a reference to the context because of memory leaks and how would you retrieve the member from the context?!

Comment: With getter. I don't see how there could be a memory leak in such case, but you could be right. I've passed reference in an Adapter constructor occasionally.

Comment: But it´s not in the context, it´s in the custom fragment implementation.. So, you can only pass this and use a getter.

Comment: In Adapter: getContext().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById().getBooleanIndicator()